# How do I convert a ASP.NET method to ASP.NET .asmx web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web

I have following asp.net method which I want to convert it into .asmx web service. How I can do that. Any help please.

```
public ActionResult AddCpty(string Id, string Type)
{
    //code for Addcp
    return result;
}
```

I am trying to convert it by putting a `[WebMethod]` attribute on the top of the method.

```
[WebMethod]
public ActionResult AddCpty(string Id, string Type)
{
    //code for Addcp
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with static

```
[WebMethod] 
public static ActionResult AddCpty(string Id, string Type) { 
//code for Addcp return result; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to access it from within the ASP template, maybe you haven't registered the route?

[See this link](http://rachelappel.com/2013/04/02/asp-net-mvc-actionresults-explained/) and find wherever your routes are being registered in your project to expose the method.